# How to describe enclosed attributes for PutItemAsync

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

I have following json

```
{
  "City": "London",
  "NrStore": 11,
  "Options": {
    "Address": "Address 1",
    "Square": 100.01,
    "ParkingSize": 101,
    "HasGroceries": false,
    "HasHouseholdGoods": false
  }
}
```

"City" - partition key

"NrStore" - sort key

Plz help me describe these model for PutItemAsync(storeInfo)

I have start so

```
var storeInfo = new Document();
storeInfo["City"] = storeBody.City;
storeInfo["NrStore"] = storeBody.NrStore;

storeInfo["StoreOptions.Address"] = storeBody.Options.Address; // ???? I dont know how to describe this enclosed attribute "Options"
```

I want to have following item in the table DynamoDB
[image]
[image]

Comment: can this help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemCRUD.html#PutItemLowLevelAPIDotNet ?

Answer (score 0):

Just save `storeBody` the way it is, in JSON format?

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve.

`PutItem(storeBody)`

If this doesn't answer your question, please edit your question and make it more clear as to what you want to achieve.

Update: this is how you would save the item using NodeJs:

```
const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-west-2" });
const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

const storeBody= {
  "City": "London",
  "NrStore": 11,
  "Options": {
    "Address": "Address 1",
    "Square": 100.01,
    "ParkingSize": 101,
    "HasGroceries": false,
    "HasHouseholdGoods": false
  }
}
    
  let res = await ddbDocClient.send(
          new PutCommand({
            TableName: "MyTable",
            Item: storeBody
          })
      );
```

Comment: I have add the pictures for clarifying

Comment: Updated answer based on your picture.

Comment: I need .Net notation. It seems to me simple json will not work

Comment: You failed to mention that in your question. This should help set you right: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/dotnet/WorkingWithItems/PutItem.cs